# CMake set_target_properties and system include directories

Tags: cmake, build-automation, include-path

When using CMake's [`include_directories`](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3ainclude_directories) command, there is a way to specify whether a given directory is a system include directory.

For various reasons, though, I have to resort to using [`set_target_properties`](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3aset_target_properties) to specify different include paths for different targets in the same scope, by setting `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property of the target.

The problem is, however, that I could not figure out how to tell CMake that a directory is a system directory so it uses `-isystem` instead of `-I` when possible. Mainly because the property is simply a list of directory paths and does not have any flags.

I thought there could be `SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`, but I could not find any mention of that.

Any thoughts on how to go about this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct way to add system directories is to use the `SYSTEM` option of the `include_directories` command:

```
include_directories(SYSTEM "/foo/bar")
```

If `include_directories` is not an option, you can specify a system include directory by directly modifying the target's `COMPILE_FLAGS` property:

```
set_target_properties(main PROPERTIES APPEND_STRING PROPERTY 
    COMPILE_FLAGS " ${CMAKE_INCLUDE_SYSTEM_FLAG_CXX} /foo/bar")
```

The variable `CMAKE_INCLUDE_SYSTEM_FLAG_CXX` usually resolves to `-isystem` on UNIX systems.

Comment: I see. That's a bit tough, but I can live with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In CMake 2.8.12, the target_include_directories() command learned the SYSTEM keyword:

http://cmake.org/gitweb?p=cmake.git;a=commitdiff;h=1925cffa083b

CMake 3.0.0 (the next release) will treat all directories listed in dependent IMPORTED targets as SYSTEM by default.

http://cmake.org/gitweb?p=cmake.git;a=commitdiff;h=a63fcbcb9f6c

Comment: Pffff... Just checked my version, it is 2.8.11. I guess I will leave with manually tweaking compile flags, hehe. Thanks for the update, though, it is helpful!